# Stack Overflow feeds not accessible from YQL?

Tags: support, feed, blocked

I am unable to access the Stack Overflow feeds from the [YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A//stackoverflow.com/feeds%27%20limit%205). Is anyone else facing the same problem are are the feeds explicitly blocked for Yahoo's IPs?

Direct curl access works fine.

```
curl http://stackoverflow.com/feeds
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a stink about this a while back, and I can't find the discussion now but apparently there is a problem with the way Yahoo Pipes and YQL handle the queries that resulting in it trying to pull down *a ton* of bandwidth over and over again.

Comment: YQL cannot make sense of gzipped content, which SO+family force (for good reason) upon consumers.

Comment: Arrrggghh.  I completely missed that this is six months old already.  Stupid community user bumps.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Pipes and Slurp (the Yahoo crawler) have been specifically blocked by both [robots.txt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) and by [IP address](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/4437171439). It is very likely that these blocks also result in YQL being blocked.