# Is Stack Overflow blocking YQL access to RSS feeds?

Tags: support, feed, blocked

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow feeds not accessible from YQL?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64172/stackoverflow-feeds-not-accessible-from-yql)

I am trying to collect some feeds from Stack Overflow. For testing purposes I tried:

```
select title,link,pubDate from rss where url in 
('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=yui&sort=newest',
  'http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=yui2&sort=newest',
  'http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=yui3&sort=newest'
)
| unique(field="link")
| sort(field="pubDate", descending="true")
```

But I am getting 'connect failure'. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Belongs to meta. However see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64172/stackoverflow-feeds-not-accessible-from-yql